# In java, how to execute similar insert queries in a single batch for cassandra database?

Tags: java, cassandra, batch-processing, datastax

My java code is given below:

```
public void execute() {

Batch batch = QueryBuilder.unloggedBatch();

SimpleStatement simpleStatement;
simpleStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);

simpleStatement = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, phone) VALUES (1, 'Abc', 9876543210)");
batch.add(simpleStatement);

simpleStatement = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, phone) VALUES (2, 'Mno', 0123456789)");
batch.add(simpleStatement);

simpleStatement = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, phone) VALUES (3, 'Xyz', 9876501234)");
batch.add(simpleStatement);

try{

    //Creating Cluster object
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();

    //Creating Session object
    Session session = cluster.connect("testkeyspace");

    //Executing the query
    session.execute(batch);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
    //Closing Cluster object
    cluster.close();
}
```

}

I am working on Java 8 & Cassandra 3.5.

I need to execute similar insert query statements in Batches to Cassandra DB using Datastax Java driver. I am trying to use Batch from datastax java driver. Also, I am trying to make a Statement object and adding it to Batch and setting the ConsistencyLevel as QUORUM.

When I execute this method, only one record gets inserted to the table. I read an article "[Cassandra: Batch loading without the Batch keyword](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/)", which states never try executing similar statements for batch execution in Cassandra DB. However, need to know how if there is an alternate solution to execute more number of queries by batch execution.

I also tried executing code samples from com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement [Examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement). Please let me know how to optimize the insertion query statements using batch execution for Cassandra DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Careful with batch statements. Its not always an optimization, actually the opposite. http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/02/cassandra-anti-pattern-misuse-of.html